# Importing a jar file with hyphens

Tags: java, import, package, jfugue

When I downloaded the jar file, it downloads as jfugue-5.0.9.jar. I loaded it into the Blue J IDE but I can't import it. With the hyphen I get a syntax error. I tried renaming it to just jfugue.jar but it says the package does not exist.

Comment: What syntax error did you get?

Comment: ',' expected. and it's highlighted right before the hyphen of the jar file name

Comment: Please edit that into the post. Thanks!

Comment: I just figured it out. Apparently the package name has nothing to do with the .jar file name. Thank you